# Iterate by two elements on a list with Java

Tags: java, list, loops, foreach

Im looking for a way to iterate by two elements in Java

For example :
i have this list : { "e1" , "e2" , "e3" , "e4" }

and i want on first iteration get { "e1" , "e2" } , on second { "e2" , "e3" }

I have already find a way to do this with Python with itertools , like this :

```
import itertools
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

...
for e1,e2 in pairwise(list) :
    # creating an element using e1 and e2
```

**I know i can do it manually in Java , but im asking is there's a defined way to do it , Thank you for your help**

Comment: So why the `python` tag?

Comment: @timgeb i already worked with it long time ago on a genetic algorithm and it works

Comment: @timgeb well that's what i want in fact sorry for writing mistake , i edited it

Comment: @TraianGEICU it will stop before reaching it , for example { e1 , e2 , e3 , e4 } : ( e1,e2) ( e2,e3 ) (e3,e4 )

Comment: check it again, it's working fine ... but maybe not answered exactly to the main question

Comment: @TraianGEICU yes i did Thank you

Comment: You have to make your own implementation of interface List, with your own Iterator. The implementation of List can be a extension of ArrayList (or whatever), but the Iterator you have to implement a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the task it's more then enough to use a regular loop and return on each step `[curent,curent+1]` list elements.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestList
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList <String> l = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d"));
    List al = new TestList().iterateList(l);
    al.forEach(System.out::println);

}
public List iterateList(List l)
{

    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList();
    if(l==null || l.size() <= 1)
    {
        //list size should be not_null and greater then 1 : 2_fine
        return null;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<l.size()-1;i++)
    {
        String element = l.get(i)+","+l.get(i+1);
        al.add(element);
    }
    return al;
}
```

Output:
`a,b`
`b,c`
`c,d`

Comment: Thanks for your help but as i mentionned in the question , i could do it manually but im asking if there is an automatic way to do it

Comment: maybe with stream could be some enhancements, but still as far as I see you need to grab on each step [curr, curr+1]

Comment: Updated, but it's mainly the same mechanism, just this time it's create a new List (maybe not the answer you wanted but ...)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, it is as simple as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = List.of("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("(" + list.get(i) + ", " + list.get(i + 1) + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
(e1, e2)
(e2, e3)
(e3, e4)
```

Comment: I already did it in same way manually but i was looking for a defined way , well thank you anyway i saw that the only way was to manually do it

Answer (score 1):

After many searchs i think the only way in Java is to do it manually

Comment: @ vinicius de novaes give antother good hint. You can also look over, but in the end each solution suppose to consume time and maybe  the less_time_consuming_solution to fit the best for some purposes.